# Facebook Android SDK No Email even after permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to get the user  email through a Facebook app. but it always return it empty. I've even given the permissions required. app also shows the message the app will get the email etc to the user.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView info;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    }
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","user_friends"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        final AccessToken accessToken= loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    info.setText(
                            "User ID: "
                                    + user.optString("email")
                                    + "\n"
                                    + user.optString("name")
                                    + "\n" +
                                    "Auth Token: "
                                    + accessToken.getToken()
                    );


                }
            }).executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}
Any idea what i'm i doing wrong here?

Comment: By permission required you mean- your email permission has been approved in facebook developer console ?? FYI due to privacy settings in some account emails are not public. Have you tried with different accounts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
executeAsync();
```

use:

the bundle parameter to Request:

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

in your Code:

```
final AccessToken accessToken= loginResult.getAccessToken();
        GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + user.optString("email")
                                + "\n"
                                + user.optString("name")
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + accessToken.getToken()
                );


            }
         });

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Also make sure the `Email` is public in your Facebook Account.